# ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' when running migrations for Django-Invitations

Tags: django, django-invitations

First, I might want to mention I'm a beginner with Django. I'm trying to install Django-Invitations on my app to send sign up invitations. I followed their [README instructions](https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations/blob/master/README.md).

```
pip install django-invitations

# Add to settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS
'invitations',

# Append to urls.py
url(r'^invitations/', include('invitations.urls', namespace='invitations')),

# Run migrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I also pip installed all the requirements from their [requirements file](https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations/blob/master/requirements.txt):

> coverage==4.5.4
> flake8==3.7.9
> freezegun==0.3.12
> mock==3.0.5
> pytest==5.2.2
> pytest-django==3.6.0
> pytest-cov==2.8.1
> tox==3.14.0

But I keep getting the same error when I run migrations for the first time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Web Development\Projects\admin\RentQ3\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Web Development\Projects\admin\RentQ3\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Web Development\Projects\admin\RentQ3\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Web Development\Projects\admin\RentQ3\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Web Development\Projects\admin\RentQ3\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Web Development\Projects\admin\RentQ3\myEnv\lib\site-packages\invitations\models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible'
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations/issues/132 - it's a known compatibility issue with Django 3.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try to build my own way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you [install six](https://pypi.org/project/six/).

All you then need to do is replace `django.utils.encoding` with `six` in your models.py.